# Point cloud using three js and NSF OpenTopography data : How do you set up the camera and a controls library to navigate the data?

Tags: javascript, three.js, point-clouds

I am working on a small project where I am attempting to display NSF OpenTopography data in a point cloud visualization using three js.  I am able to create the point cloud but running into serious issues with the camera setup and camera navigation.  I have tried using various controls (OrbitControls.js, TrackballControls.js and a FirstPersonControls.js) but all have come up short. Below is a link to a working copy of where I am at with the visualization.  My goals is to be able to plot the point cloud data and use maybe the mouse or arrow keys to navigate the scene.

http://jsfiddle.net/mcroteau/ycg1hqu0/

Please let me know if additional code and or examples are needed.  The jsfiddle above is just one attempt at many to get something to work.

Any guidance would be most appreciated.

**Javascript**

```
var container, scene, 
    camera, renderer, 
    controls, stats,
    geometry, material;

var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, 
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, 
    ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 
    NEAR = 0.1, 
    FAR = 20000;

var POINT_SIZE = 1;

var BACKGROUND_COLOR = 0xefefef,
    POINT_COLOR = 0x4466B0;

var maxX = maxY = maxZ = 0;
var minX = minY = minZ = 0;
var midX = midY = midZ = 0;

var step = 1;
var lookZ = lookX = 0;


init();
animate();


function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    if ( Detector.webgl ){
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    }else{
        renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer(); 
    }

    renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    renderer.setClearColor( BACKGROUND_COLOR, 1);

    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


    stats = new Stats();
    stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    stats.domElement.style.bottom = '0px';
    stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
    container.appendChild( stats.domElement );


    geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++ ) {
        var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();

        /** 
        correct x, y, z values 
        camera seems really out of position when using these values
        **/
        //var x = data[i][0];
        //var y = data[i][1];
        //var z = data[i][2];

        var x = data[i][1];
        var y = data[i][2];
        var z = data[i][0];


        vertex.x = x;
        vertex.y = y;
        vertex.z = z;
        geometry.vertices.push(vertex);

        if(i < 10){
            console.log([x, y, z]);
        }
        checkSetMaxValues(x, y, z, i);
    }

    setMedians()

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
    camera.position.x = minX  - 20
    camera.position.y = maxY + 20
    camera.position.z = minZ - 20

    scene.position.x = midX
    scene.position.y = minY
    scene.position.z = midZ

    scene.add(camera);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    //controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

    lookZ = camera.position.z
    lookX = camera.position.x


    material = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial( { size: POINT_SIZE, color : POINT_COLOR } );
    particles = new THREE.PointCloud( geometry, material );
    scene.add( particles );

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

function setMedians(){
    midX = (maxX + minX) / 2;
    midY = (maxY + minY) / 2;
    midZ = (maxZ + minZ) / 2;
    console.info('mid', midX, midY, midZ);
}


function checkSetMaxValues(x, y, z, i){
    if(x > maxX || maxX === 0)maxX = x
    if(x < minX || minX === 0)minX = x
    if(y > maxY || maxY === 0)maxY = y
    if(y < minY || minY === 0)minY = y
    if(z > maxZ || maxZ === 0)maxZ = z
    if(z < minZ || minZ === 0)minZ = z

    if(data.length == i + 1){
        console.log('max:', maxX, maxY, maxZ)
        console.log('min:', minX, minY, minZ)
    }
}


function onWindowResize() {
    var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}


function animate() {
    render();       
    update();
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}



function update(){
    stats.update();
    updateCamera();
    //would like to use a controls library
    //controls.update()
}



function updateCamera(){

    if(lookZ < maxZ){
        camera.position.z = camera.position.z + 0.20;
        lookZ = camera.position.z
    }

    if(lookZ >= maxZ){
        if(lookX < maxX){
            camera.position.x = camera.position.x + 0.20;
            lookX = camera.position.x
        }
    }

    camera.lookAt(scene.position)
}


function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Comment: Not sure to understand your question and the problem in the fiddle. What are you trying to do ? What are the issues with `OrbitControls` and `TrackballControls` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that Orbit Controls cant handle your insane scene size. When the cameras `position` is set to such high values, the rotation speed and zoom adapt (its moving faster). But the general bounding box of your visual data isnt that big, so I guess it moves instantly out of the viewing space.

I solved this by recentering your geometry using `geometry.center();` and not modifying the `scene.position`. Here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/ycg1hqu0/9/